# Referencing Controls inside am ajax Tab

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, gridview

I have an ajax tab which inside has a grid, on this grid there is a check box where the user has the ability to check it and assign it to a technician, but for some reason im unable to reference the control, the grid has a total of 4 rows so there is data there, this is my code which is run of a button click

```
protected void btnAllocate_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (System.Web.UI.Control s in tbHappyCall.Controls)
            {
               foreach (GridViewRow Row in gvHappyCall.Rows)
                {
                    CheckBox chkAllocate = (CheckBox)Row.FindControl("chkAllocate");

                    if (chkAllocate.Checked)
                    {
                        HyperLink lblOrderID = (HyperLink)Row.FindControl("hyperOrderID");

                        HappyCallManager objHappyCallManager = new HappyCallManager();

                        objHappyCallManager.HappyCallAllocated(Convert.ToInt64(lblOrderID.Text), objWebuser.ShortAbbr, ddlAllocateTo.SelectedValue);

                        //Update database with person details thats are assigned to the Welcome Call

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

when it goes on to the Foreach gridviewrow etc the count is 1 even though there is 4 rows displaying information ?

Can any one shed any light on this? or even better a solution?

Thank you for your time.

UPdate

```
<ajaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="tbHappyCall" runat="server" HeaderText="Welcome Calls" TabIndex="10">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <%--OnRowDataBound="gvConfirmOrder_rowDataBound"--%>
                    <div id="divHappyCall">
                        <asp:GridView ID="gvHappyCall" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" class="tablesorter"
                            EmptyDataText="There is no Record to display." DataKeyNames="OrderID" EnableViewState="false"
                            OnRowDataBound="gvHappyCall_RowDataBound">
                            <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="NormalTextVNC" BackColor="#E2E9E7"></AlternatingRowStyle>
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Account Manager">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblAccountManager" CssClass="gvItem" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.AccountManager") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="OrderID">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:HyperLink ID="hyperOrderID" runat="server" ForeColor="White" NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("OrderGuid","/Documents/HappyCall.aspx?OrderID={0}") %>'
                                            Text='<%#Eval("OrderID") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Customer Name">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblCustomerName" CssClass="gvItem" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.CustomerName") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Company Name">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblCompanyName" CssClass="gvItem" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.CompanyName") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Mobile Number">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblMobileNumber" CssClass="gvItem" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.MobileNumber") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Dispatch Date">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblConnectionDate" CssClass="gvItem" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.DespatchDate") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" CssClass="gvItem" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Status") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>  
                               <asp:BoundField headertext="Date Called" dataformatstring="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"   datafield="EditedDate" HeaderStyle-Width="100px"  />
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Allocated To">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblAllocatedTo" CssClass="gvItem" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.AllocatedTo") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            <%--<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last Action">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblLAstAction" CssClass="gvItem" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.LastAction") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>--%>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Check">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                      <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkAssignWelcomeCall" />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>
                        </asp:GridView>
                        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlAllocateTo" CssClass="floatright">
                        <asp:ListItem>Name of Admin to Allocate</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <div class="WhiteSpace"></div>
                        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnAllocate" class="floatright" Text="Allocate" OnClick="btnAllocate_click" />
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
```

Comment: Where is `btnAllocate`, where and what is `tbHappyCall`, why do you iterate it's controls when you can  reference `gvHappyCall` directly and you never use the variable `s` at all?

Comment: BtnAllocate is located under the gridview, sorry tbHappyCall is the name of the Ajax tab, and i tried referencing gvHappyCall directly but again it only returns a count of 1 even though there is 4 rows in there so i done some googling regarding ajax tabs with controls inside and i come across a blog where it stated i had to foreach control etc.

Comment: Have you used the debugger to see what happens? I assume that there's an exception somewhere. What is the DataSource of the grid(f.e. `DataTable` or `SqlDataSource`)? Are you rebinding the GridView on every postback in page_load or only on first load? Can you show the aspx markup of the GridView?

Comment: Hi, Iv added the HTML markup above, i use a datatable to bind the grid, iv used the debugger and again thats where i noticed it has a count of one when i look inside the count of controls, but when i foreach gridview row etc it doesnt even enter that loop

Comment: iv just commented out the Foreach control s part of my code and tried referencing the grid directly again, and again i get a count of 0? when it does a post back from the button click it doesnt bind the grid again so i only bind it on first load

Comment: Apart from the problem that there are no rows in the grid, you are using the wrong id for the checkbox. So instead of `chkAllocate` you should use `chkAssignWelcomeCall` since that is the only `CheckBox` in your grid.

Comment: Good spot thanks for that, thats one furture problem sorted, now i just need to figure out why it wont count the rows.....

Comment: Where are you loading the `TabPanel` and the `GridView`, is it lazy-loaded from `TabContainer.ActiveTabChanged`(recommended) or loaded in `Page_Load`?

Comment: its on page load if(!IsPostBack) { in here } iv followed the code through, and just cant seem to figure out why it doesnt count the rows which i find weird...because i done something similar on another page within my project and that works perfectly, and basically mirrored the code from one page to another

Comment: So you are preloading all TabPanels in the first place. I recommend [**lazy-loading**](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/07/how_to_lazyload_tabpanels_with.html). But i don't see how this would solve your issue. How and where do you recognize the difference, 4 rows are in database, 1 row is displayed and 0 rows "are in the foreach"? When the grid is loaded(first page_load) it has 4 rows, when you use the debugger in the event handler it has 1 row, but it doesn't enter the `foreach` anyway? Can you shed some light on this?

Comment: When i load the page for the first time i have a total of 4 rows which are also displayed to the user, when i remove the foreach(control) i get a count of 0 for gridviewrows, but when i put the foreach control back in the code i get a count of 7 controls when i debug "s" even if i call the method which binds the grid for the first time it will remove any checkboxes that have been checked.

Comment: For clarification: you don't need to iterate the control collection of your TabPanel to find your GridView, it is available directly and don't confuse it's `Controls.Count` with the number of `GridView.Rows.Count`. Another question: is ViewState disabled somewhere? **Edit** I see that the GridView's ViewState is disabled. I assume that it works when you enable it ;)

Comment: ViewState was set to False!!!!!! made it true and its working now! i hate mondays lol Tim Thank you so much for your help and time on this! really do appreciate it!! have a good day

Answer (score 0):

For clarification: you don't need to iterate the control collection of your `TabPanel` to find your `GridView`, it is available directly and don't confuse it's `Controls.Count` with the number of `GridView.Rows.Count`.

Is ViewState disabled somewhere?

**Edit**: I see that the GridView's ViewState is disabled. I assume that it works when you enable it.